# How to put 2 lists into 1 Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

So this is the situation: I have 2 lists and want to put them in a dictionary.

Content  ['This is Sams Content', 'This is someone's else content']
Author  ['Sam', 'Someone Else']

This is the dictionary I would like to create

Reviews [{'content': 'This is Sams Content', 'author' : 'Sam'} , {'content': 'This is someone's else content', 'author' : 'Someone Else'}

I hope you understand what the question is. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for zip I believe.  Something like this:

```
reviews = [{'content': c, 'author': a} for c, a in zip(contentList, authorList)]
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't seen zip() before. :)

Comment: It's essential.  It aids in this type of situation to no end.

Comment: hehe even better than Simon's answer although Simon's answer is more readable for python newbs like me. Gotta read the zip documentation.

Comment: @Sam - At first list comprehensions look a little bit complex, but once you work with them for a little bit you'll never want to go back to a language without them.

Comment: Yea I know. I use them quite a lot now too for simple operations with lists and dictionaries. I really like them ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
content = ['This is Sams Content', 'This is someone\'s else content'] 
author = ['Sam', 'Someone Else']

reviews = []

for i in range(len(author)):
    d = {
        'content': content[i],
        'author': author[i]
    }
    reviews.append(d)

for r in reviews:
    print "Author: %s, content: %s" % (r['author'], r['content'])
```

---

**EDIT** for those who complained that `range(len(...))` isn't sufficiently Pythonic (to which I say merely "seriously?"), here's the same solution using `enumerate()` as suggested:

```
content = ['This is Sams Content', 'This is someone\'s else content'] 
author = ['Sam', 'Someone Else']

reviews = []

for i, elem in enumerate(author):
    d = {
        'content': content[i],
        'author': elem,
    }
    reviews.append(d)

for r in reviews:
    print "Author: %s, content: %s" % (r['author'], r['content'])
```

Personally I prefer the `range(len(...))` solution over `enumerate`, because accessing both arrays in the same style when creating the hash aids readability. `zip` is still the most elegant solution though.

Comment: Thanks really clear answer. Should have been able to figure this out with the documentation, but I always find it a little hard to read the python documentation. It seems not so well structured.

Comment: Glad it helped Sam! The docs get easier to read the more you read them and the more Python you write, so stick with it! :)

Comment: `range(len(...))` is not python - use `enumerate(...)`. But the bettere solution for the question is to use `zip`.

Comment: It looks like python to me. :) I think you mean that it's not idiomatic python, which is fair enough - but it works and it's easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
reviews = []
authors = ['sam', 'dave']
content = ['content by sam', 'content by dave']
for a, c in zip(authors, content):
    reviews.append({'content':c, 'author':a})
print reviews
```

Comment: g.d.d.c.'s answer is more concise and pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Content and Author are arrays as defined in the question, and assuming you want a single resulting dict:

```
d = {}

for i in range(len(Content)):
   d[Content[i]] = Author[i]
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(x))` is a no-go in python unless you're really only juggling with indices. -1

Comment: @delnan: can you provide some documentation to support this? I'm assuming you're talking about it being non-pythonic, which is fine, but it **does** work :)

Comment: Documentation? Just ask *any* experienced python coder... just look at the code samples in *any* python book/tutorial with good rep... yeah, it "works", but it is inferior to the idiomatic alternative in **any** way.

Comment: @dls, if you need to iterate through something while keeping an index counter, use `for i, x in enumerate(Content)`.

Comment: @delnan Documentation helps separate facts from opinion. enumerate looks pretty and is no doubt more Pythonic (whatever that means), but does it actually affect runtime performance? If so, it would be informative for you to link to the evidence so that others can learn from it. If not, you're effectively just turning SO into a beauty contest. IMO, voting a correct answer down because it answers the problem in a style not in keeping with your personal preference undermines the purpose of SO and gives a bad impression of the dev community of your language.

Comment: @Simon: Downvoting might be debatable (perhaps I wouldn't now), but I'd never upvote this answer. Apart from a marginal speed difference in favour of `enumerate` (it won't be an issue in most cases, but it's measureable - especially when `xs[i]` is used several times, as you avoid multiple lookups), it is idiomatic while the other is not. Using idioms correctly isn't important for correctness - but then again, neither are descriptive names, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Indexing into an array is about the most efficient operation you can perform, regardless of the size of the array. If you get to the point where an additional index into an array is causing performance problems you shouldn't be using a scripting language. :)